# How can I sync Stardew Valley between Xbox One and PC?

Tags: stardew-valley

I started Stardew Valley this morning on the Xbox One and I'd like to continue playing on my laptop. However, after installing, launching, and logging into Xbox Live on my laptop with it, I'm surprised to find that my progress isn't available.

I've read [the wiki page on game saves](https://stardewvalleywiki.com/Saves) and it doesn't mention anything about Xbox One, unfortunately.

---

How can I sync Stardew Valley between Xbox One and PC?

Comment: Is it available on Windows Store for PC? I see it there, but can't tell if its available for PC too.   I know you can get it on Steam

Comment: Is there any reason you believe you'd be able to do this? I've never heard of this being possible in any game that wasn't fully online.

Comment: @TimmyJim I play it using the XBOX app through GamePass on PC.

Comment: @BlueRaja-DannyPflughoeft it was an assumption.

Answer (score 3):

**You can't**.

The game, in its current form, doesn't have cross-platform support.

This means that you cannot play online multiplayer between any of the systems the game is on. That also means if you want to team up with some friends, make sure you all are playing on the same platform, such as the Switch, PS4, PS5, Xbox One, Series X, Android, Steam, etc.

So it isn't possible to sync your world between your Xbox One and PC.

---

For some added info. The Developer of the game posted the following [tweet](https://twitter.com/ConcernedApe/status/1036993838613651459?t=a5bWFfmdC0oyYobiLugfMg&s=19) back in 2018 on his Twitter:

> Unfortunately, there will not be crossplay. Apparently, the technical barriers are very high. It’s still something I really want to add and I promise to look into it more closely, but first priority is getting the update out there

Comment: Great answer! Do you have any official documentation you could share in your answer to cover the lack of cross-platform support?

Comment: @Hazelへいぜる Yes. I updated my answer. The developer tweeted it.